# Python - Is stdout always "available"?

Tags: python, linux, io

I have written an API where the user can direct the output of a sql query to:

1> Excel (class ExcelOut)
2> CSV (class CSVOut)
3> Standard Output (class StdOut)

For the first 2 output types, I expect the user to provide me a file location , then the API checks if the location exists a.k.a argument validation
For standard output, i am wondering if there is any validation needed? i.e. is there ever any case where the *user(a developer) of the API is not aware that sys.stdout is not "available"* when the code runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons why stdout would not be writable. Here are some examples:

```
# 1. Run with stdout explicitly closed:
$ ./yourscript >&- 

# 2. Run in the background and then closing the terminal
$ ./yourscript & exit

# 3. No space on the device (/dev/full simulates this for testing):
$ ./yourscript > /dev/full

# 4. Run with a pipe that closes immediately:
$ ./yourscript | true

# 5. Run with a pipe that closes after the first 10 lines:
$ ./yourscript | head -n 10
```

On a write, each error be wrapped in a Python IOError with Errno set to:

1. `EBADF (Bad file descriptor)`
2. `EIO (Input/output error)`
3. `ENOSPC (No space left on device)`
4. `EPIPE (Broken pipe)`
5. The first several write calls will succeed, and then `EPIPE` as in #4 (in other words, working once does not mean working always).

It's rarely useful to try to determine if stdout is valid before starting to write to it though (basic checks can be done with e.g. `os.fstat`). Most programs should just assume it's available, and handle failures gracefully.

Comment: thanks for your input. 1, 2, 4 and 5 seem deliberate attempts to not have the stdout available. Maybe I should have been explicit in my question, but i am looking for scenarios where the user is not aware of sys.stdout not being available(the reason being that I expect the user would still be a developer).

Comment: oh and a question, would full disk affect standard out if the standard out is text terminal? My apologizes if this is a dumb question, but i was under the impression that printing it to screen does not incur any disk space usage

Comment: @name_masked It looks deliberate because it's the shortest way of reproducing the same conditions. We can [search github](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=stdout+%22bad+file+descriptor%22+site:github.com) for real world cases of 1. 2 can easily happen when using xinetd and cgi scripts. 4 and 5 could both be due to an innocent looking `./yourscript | gawk -F , '{print $1}' > file`.

Comment: @name_masked You're very unlikely to get ENOSPC directly when writing to a tty. However, a ENOSPC can cause the terminal emulator to fail and return an EIO.